# Angular 16, extend builders to perform custom task on compile

Tags: angular, angular-devkit

I have an Angular 16 app which I compile by `ng build <project> --watch`.
The app is served by external web server (caddy) hence the `--watch`.
So now when I edit any source file, the app is re-compiled, all good so far.
However I have some translation files (.properties) that I want to perform additional operation on. In this case to convert the .properties files to json, that is expected by Angular's translation system and store it on disk.

I read that `ng <command>` things are called builders, part of the angular devkit. However it is not clear to me how can I extend, if possible, the builders, to add additional step (convert to json and store on disk).

Questions:

- What would be a proper approach to achieve above
- Should I just create a custom `TranslateLoader` that will parse the language files. But in this case, every time the app loads, I have to parse the language files, which could be big.

Comment: No need to bother with angular. Simply write a script that will be executed by npm.

Comment: But changing a translation file will not trigger recompile. I would like `--watch` to work

Comment: use one of the filewatcher packages to trigger a transformation. If you import your files directly into your app, then app rebuild will be triggered right after JSON is saved. Not very sexy, requires two terminal windows but is less time consuming to implement. But of you go with builders, post an update here with the source code :) maybe it will be useful for someone as an example.